# linux ubuntu 15.04 vim ruby.vim imap <S-CR> <CR><CR>end<ESC>

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vim

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and vim-gnome 7.4.

When I run:

```
vim --version | grep -i +ruby
```

It returns:

```
+ruby
```

Based on: [Vim Ruby Support site:](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport)

I can add the following to my .vimrc file:

```
imap <S-CR> <CR><CR>end<ESC>-cc
```

and type:

```
if name == "John"[<--cursor] (and hit Shift Enter)
```

should produce the following:

```
 if name == "John"
  [<--cursor]
end
```

but in my case it does not.

when I type in vim:

```
:map <S-CR>
```

to see if it returns a maping I don't get anything.

I do however have a line within my vimrc:

```
map
map!
```

To see if everything maps correctly and I get no errors and everything looks as it should.

Does anyone know why it is not working?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers.

Comment: Nothing in your problem is related to Ruby support. `:map <S-CR>` won't show you your insert mode mapping, use `:imap <S-CR>` for that.

Comment: Where do you attempt to trigger the mapping? `<S-CR>` will work in GVIM, but it might not in terminals (many of which don't handle modifier keys + Enter).

Comment: Might want to look into Tim Pope's [endwise.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise) plugin.

Comment: Thanks Romainl, I used imap sorry that was my typo. Still does not work.

Comment: Hi Ingo Karkat, I know that some modifier keys in terminal don't work. I am using bash, but I have in my .bashrc file the following line: stty -ixon, which I understand disables terminal from intercepting certain command keys used by terminal, but don't quote me on this. I don't remember where I read it. Else I would post the link here. :(

Comment: Hi Ingo, I tried gvim and it works partially. It indents and adds the "end" termination, but it does not place the [<--cursor] part on the following line. Is there a work around to get this to work in vim from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I figured it out. What isn't working is my brain. It is working just fine in vim-gnome. I was typing the [<--cursor], which it obviously doesn't recognize. If I "hit enter" after "John". it closes the if statement.

Sorry! thanks for the help.